# Node Socket.IO socket.on() across multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO in a node app and I wish to catch and respond to socket events in different files, how do I do it?

One solution that I was able to find was to do this in the file that sets up the socket.io:

```
var events = [];
module.exports.setup = (server) => {
  io = require('socket.io')(server);
  console.log("Socket.io setup complete");
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    for(let e of events){
      socket.on(e.event, e.callback);
    }
  });
};

module.exports.on = (event, callback) => {
  events.push({event: event, callback: callback});
};
```

This works just fine, the only problem is that I can't reach the socket object, thus I don't know which socket emitted the event.

**EDIT**

Well I guess one other way is to pass the socket in the cb as the first argument, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: How about logging the `socket.id`?

Comment: @asosnovsky can you elaborate on that?

Comment: take a look at the doc for socket.io https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-id

Comment: @asosnovsky Well I know that, what I'm asking is how can I access the socket object when using the exported `on` function. Or any other way to register socket events in different files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to structure things depending upon how your code is structured and how you might want to reuse or structure your modules.  Here are some of the choices:

1. Pass `io` to every module's constructor that wants to listen for incoming socket.io events and let every module that wants to listen for a message, use that `io` value to create its own `io.on('connection', socket => { socket.on('someMsg', localHandler)} );`.
2. Export `io` from your main socket.io module and then have every module that wants to listen to an incoming message `import/require()` the main socket.io module (to get the `io` value) and then use that `io` value to create its own `io.on('connection', socket => { socket.on('someMsg', localHandler)} );`.
3. Have your main socket.io module export a function for registering a listener for an incoming socket.io message and then just have one `io.on('connection', ...)` handler in your main socket.io module that listens for all the events that were requested.